# Searching Xml Document with linq doesn't return anything

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to learn how to save and extract data with XML in C#, and even though I've read various answers to similar questions on here, I cannot get a hold of why my statement isn't returning anything. 
The program I'm writing is just a test, in which I've saved data about a couple movies in the xml document and now I'm trying to retrieve some of them based on their cost.

This is the class that I've written for searching:

```
 class ExtractData
{
    private XDocument _xdoc;
    public List<string> SearchByCost(double cost)
    {
        _xdoc = XDocument.Load(FileLocation.XmlFileLocation);
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        var movies = from movie in _xdoc.Root.Elements("Name")
                where Convert.ToDouble(movie.Element("Cost").Value) < cost
                select movie;

        foreach (var item in movies)
        {
            list.Add(item.Value);
        }

        return list;
    }

}
```

This is how I'm trying to make it print it in the console:

```
        eData = new ExtractData();
        foreach (var movie in eData.SearchByCost(9))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(movie);
        }
```

And this is the content of the XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Movies>
  <Movie>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>Shawshank Redemption</Name>
    <Director>Frank Darabont</Director>
    <Year>1994</Year>
    <Cost>9.95</Cost>
  </Movie>
  <Movie>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>Pulp Fiction</Name>
    <Director>Quentin Tarantino</Director>
    <Year>1995</Year>
    <Cost>8.95</Cost>
  </Movie>
  <Movie>
    <Id>3</Id>
    <Name>Sharknado</Name>
    <Director>Anthony Ferrante</Director>
    <Year>2013</Year>
    <Cost>5.95</Cost>
  </Movie>
</Movies>
```

I hope this is enough information to try and help me out, and thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You need to debug your code.  Also, `var movies = from movie in _xdoc.Root.Elements("Name")` that selects (possibly--it may not return anything, but if it does...) all <Name> elements.  Then you attempt to retrieve the cost via `movie.Element("Cost")`, but the <name> element *doesn't have any child elements!!*  At a minimum, you need to change it to `_xdoc.Root.Elements("Movie")` and do a `select movie.Elements("Name")` or similar at the end to get all the names of the movies that match.

Comment: Thanks, I had apparently gotten the element names a bit mixed up in that linq query. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Root element contains `Movie` elements:

```
var movies = from movie in _xdoc.Root.Elements("Movie")  // here instead of "Name"
             where (double)movie.Element("Cost") < cost
             select movie;
```

Also, `XElement` supports explicit casting to double. And you can replace the second loop with LINQ query (assume you want to select names of movies):

```
List<string> list = movies.Select(m => (string)m.Element("Name")).ToList();
```

Comment: You are too kind to take the time and answer that question.

Answer (score 1):

In plain English, you seem to be trying to find movies cheaper than 9 (of some arbitrary currency).

You can write this as:

```cs
public IReadOnlyCollection<string> SearchByCost(XDocument xdoc, double cost) 
{
    return xdoc.Root.Elements("Movie")
        .Where(movie => (double)movie.Element("Cost") < cost)
        .Select(movie => movie.Element("Name").Value)
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Haha yea, exactly - in a real life application the currency and other things would of course be specififed, but this is just for getting the hang of xml. I actually got it working not only with the name, but with returning a list of MovieDTO's instead:

(Whoops, code formatting doesn't work in comments :D But yea, it works as intended now! Thanks for the help :)!)